# "int() argument must be a string" from int(p.returncode) with subprocess.Popen object

Tags: python-3.x, bash, subprocess, tar

I am developing a Python 3 program to backup by rsync remote folders into local NAS.

I rsync the folder perfectly but when I want to compress by .tar.gz the folder into a file I get this error:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
file changed as we read it
tar: write error
```

The function that generates the compressed file is this one:

```
def make_tarfile(self, output_filename, source_dir):
    try:
        # Generate .tar.gz
        print("Generating .tar.gz backup")
        tar_args = ['tar', '-cvzf', source_dir+output_filename+'.tar.gz', source_dir]
        process = subprocess.Popen(
                tar_args,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE
            )
        if int(process.returncode) != 0:
            print('Command failed. Return code : {}'.format(process.returncode))
        print("OK.")

        # Remove files
        print("Removing files previously compressed.")
        remove_args = ['find', source_dir, '-type f', '!', '-name "*.?*"', '-delete']
        process = subprocess.Popen(
                remove_args,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE
            )
        print("OK.")
        if int(process.returncode) != 0:
            print('Command failed. Return code : {}'.format(process.returncode))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        exit(1)
```

If I write the command by bash seems to work.

Comment: Use `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.Popen`. It waits for the command to finish.

Comment: `process.returncode` isn't set until the software is done running.

Comment: It's not kosher to edit in a way that invalidates existing answers after your question has been answered in a way that was correct for how it was initially asked. Ask a new question when you encounter a new problem.

Comment: That said, `'-type f'` needs to be `'-type', 'f'`

Comment: Similarly, `'-name "*.?*"'` is supposed to be `'-name', '*.?*'`

Comment: ...anything that the shell would parse into two words needs to be two separate elements in your Python list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new `subprocess.Popen` object *starts* a process. It doesn't wait for it to finish, and no `returncode` exists for an unfinished process.

The historical way to wait for a Popen object to finish is to call the `wait()` function on it. You can also use `subprocess.run` instead, or some other helper such as `communicate()` that itself implicitly waits for completion.

Comment: Hi Charles, I have edited my question. I tried with run, but I get "tar: Removing leading `/' from member names" and also "tar: /backup/rsync/equipelectronics.com/11-04-2020/01\:12\:50: file changed as we read it".

Comment: Both those messages are completely normal, and have nothing at all to do with Python.

Comment: They both mean exactly what they say: it's normal for tar to remove leading `/`s from filenames (and to write a warning when it does so), and it's normal for tar to write a warning to stderr when a file it's archiving changes under it. These are both *warnings*, not *errors*.

Comment: ...to avoid that second issue, best practice is to use any snapshot-type mechanism your filesystem or underlying block device layer offers to get a stable image of an instant in time, and create your backup off that image. It's well outside the scope of this question, though (whether it's even possible for you at all depends on a bunch of OS and filesystem setup/configuration details).

Comment: I understand what you say, but If the .tar.gz had been created properly, there would not a "Command failed. Return code : 1", it would be a 0. Also when I open the .tar.gz with WinRar it sayas that is damaged and if I open it, here are only some files.

Comment: Again, that's not Python's problem. Whether a file changes underneath tar during any given run depends on what other software is running at the same time (and actually performing those changes), so it isn't going to be 100% reliable about when it happens and when it doesn't.

Comment: See discussion in https://superuser.com/questions/543633/tar-file-changed-as-we-read-it, https://superuser.com/questions/1493104/tar-error-wp-content-file-changed-as-we-read-it, etc.

Comment: ...if you *want* full control from Python, use the [Python `tarfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) instead of running the external `tar` command..

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles. Finally I decided to use tarfile module and I got the expected result.